# Can't request data from website to Arduino using PHP and JSON

Tags: json, arduino-esp8266, vs-web-site-project, lcd

[image]

Please help me. I did many and various way including changing flash firmware many versions but still it cannot request data from my website to display on Arduino LCD. I also try a few coding with wifiesp and without still it cannot read my Json file.

```cpp
void loop() {
  String payload = "";
  bool parse_json = false;
  char web_host[] = "putraelection.000webhostapp.com";
  if (client.connect(web_host, 80)) {
    Serial.println("CONNECT HOST");
    String url = "/reqdatacalon.php";
    client.print("GET " + url + "HTTP/1.0\r\n" +
    "Host: " + web_host + "\r\n" +
    //"Accept: application/json\r\n" +
    //"Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
    "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n" +
    "\r\n");
        
    while (client.connected() || client.available()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        //char c = client.read();
        String b = client.readString();
        Serial.println(b);
        /*if (c == '{') {
          parse_json = true;
        }
        if (parse_json) {
          payload += c;
        }*/
      }
    }
    client.stop();
  }
  Serial.print("data");
  Serial.println(payload);
  payload.trim();
  if (payload != "") {
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
    if (error) {
      Serial.println("ERROR JSON");
    } else {
      String can1 = doc["CANDIDATE 1"];
      Serial.println ("calon 1:" +can1);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("data kosong");
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Please, there is no need to SHOUT AT US

Comment: I also do not see any PHP code, please dont SPAM TAGS they are there for a reason, ro attract the right audience for your question, not to gather a mod